# PHP and MYSQL - Querying A Variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok, I have this PHP $_POST['username'] variable and I need to query everything on the user via MYSQL. The only problem is it keeps throwing me errors.

something like

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $user");
```

I've tried

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = `$user`");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ".$user);
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: what errors???? (Ignore the excessive question marks, they are there to circumvent the comment character limit. I am not surprised, just asking what the errors are.)

Comment: DO NOT directly use user input in a query string. DO read about `SQL injection`. DO read about `parameterized queries`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that strings in SQL need to be enclosed in single quotes.

The most preferable approach would be to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  But [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) (along with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)) is a better interim approach that what is posted:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT u.* 
                    FROM USER u
                   WHERE u.username = '%s'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Lest we forget [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$query = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE "' . $user . '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$user'");
```